# From 2D to 3D using convolutional autoencoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I’d like to reconstruct 3D object from 2D images.
For that, I try to use convolutional auto encoder. However, in which layer should I lift the dimensionality?

I wrote a code below, however, it shows an error:

> “RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: size ‘[1 x 1156 x 1156]’ is invalid for input of with 2312 elements at pytorch-src/torch/lib/TH/THStorage.c:41”

```
class dim_lifting(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(dim_lifting, self).__init__()
        self.encode = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 34, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(34, 16, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 8, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.LeakyReLU()
        )

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2312, 2312)
        self.decode = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose3d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.encode(x)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = out.view(1, 1156, 1156)
        out = self.decode(out)
        return out
```

Error happens here

```
out = out.view(1, 1156, 1156)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the dimensions specified in `out = out.view(1, 1156, 1156)` are correct? It seems like you cannot fit an input with 2312 elements in 1*1156*1156=1336336

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test my suggestion because your example is not complete. 
I think your line should like

```
out = out.view(x.size(0), -1)
```

this way you're flattening out your input.